# Oracle CONTAINS Giving Invalid Identifier ORA-00904

Tags: sql, oracle, contains, oracle-sqldeveloper, ora-00904

So I have a webapp that takes in a string where ID elements are broken up by '-' (e.g. `someid1-someid2`). I then convert the string to something like `someid1 OR someid2`. This in theory according to [Oracle's doc's](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/cqoper.htm#1531) should allow me to then do something like

```
SELECT somecol1, somecol2 FROM sometable WHERE CONTAINS (somecol1, 'someid1 OR someid2') > 0;
```

However I'm getting the following error when running the sample query in SQL Dev:

> ORA-00904: "CONTAINS": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:    
>   *Action:

The version of Oracle is `Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.5.0 - Production` of which the documentation is for, so I don't see why `CONTAINS` would be considered an invalid identifier. Adding the other optional parameter

```
SELECT somecol1, somecol2 FROM sometable WHERE CONTAINS (somecol1, 'someid1 OR someid2', 1) > 0;
```

also gives the same error. What am I/it doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**
'Working Code' as per request although arguably it isn't working

```
SELECT tech, product FROM tech_det_view WHERE CONTAINS (tech, 'test OR qual') > 0;
```

Comment: It looks good but I think it's fake code. Could you include working code ?

Comment: Someone's going to say it; extended support on 9.2 ended over 7 years ago now. Have you considered upgrading?

Comment: I am but a lowly intern; I doubt I have the influence over corporate or could justify pushing all of the DBs to be upgraded to something newer especially since 9.2 supports CONTAINS

Comment: @Parado Correct it's a pseudo code query where I just did find & replace, but now you have the original query, should it be of any use...

Comment: @KurtWagner Looks fine. Have you created the required Oracle Text index?

Comment: @Parado I was actually just about to mention that. I ran the same query against the dev/mock 'environment' (older data to safely mess with, but newer Oracle versions) and got `ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10599: column is not indexed`. So perhaps the v9.2 DBs aren't 'smart' enough and give a 'bad' error? Do I need a unique index for CONTAINS (eg several columns) or am I OK if there are a few duplicates for this column and just index this one column?

Comment: @KurtWagner See the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18774996/1579182)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create `oracle text index` before using `CONTAINS` function

```
CREATE INDEX idxName ON tableName(columnName) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;
```

**[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96517/cdefault.htm)** you can find more information about **Oracle Text**.

Comment: `Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01702: a view is not appropriate here
01702. 00000 -  "a view is not appropriate here"`
So I take it I index the column/table that the view actually pulls from then? Or will I still get the previous index error because my actual query is pulling from a view?

Comment: @KurtWagner Ah `tech_det_view` is it a view?! Could you include the view body? Or tell me in which table you have got `tech` column?

Comment: It looks like you updated your answer. I changed to table/col ref'd in the view and am currently running into privilege issues despite it being the mock environment. If it fixes the issue, worst case I can just run the SQL query in the mock environment to use the CONTAINS function (should it not work in production) and link to production data. I'm pretty sure this indexing is the answer, but I'll mark it as such as soon as I get the privileges and am able to index it to confirm!